# Custom background image for jquery UI tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, tooltip

I want to set a custom background image for jquery UI tootltip.
 Is it posible?
I use jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js.

I tried the following css.But not perfect.

```
.ui-tooltip-content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    background: url("images/tooltipImage.png") scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your are looking for?

```
.ui-tooltip {
    background: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/light-wooden-background.jpg") scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-size:2000px 60px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

See Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/kyBwU/1347/